# ¿Por que el resultado de la siguiente función es NaN?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que pedir al usuario que introduzca números y cuando introduzca un número negativo debo sumar los números anteriormente ingresados y al usar la siguiente función el resultado de la suma (sume) me da **`NaN`**. ¿Alguien sabe por que?

```js
let result = [];
    
const pushNum = ()=>{
    let num = 0;
    while (num>=0){
        num = parseInt(prompt('ingrese un número: ', '0'));
        if (num>=0){
           result.push(num);
           num=0;
        }  
    }
    console.log(result);
    let sume = 0;
    console.log(sume);
    for (let i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
        sume = sume + result[i];
    }
    console.log(`La suma es: ${sume}`);
}

pushNum();
```

Comment: El problema es en el `<=`, debería ser `<` está buscando una posición que no existe al final

Answer (score 1):

Expandiré la respuesta de Emeeus.

Tal y como dice, dentro del último for, le has dado el siguiente simbolo:

- `<=` : Menor o igual que

Al momento de contar, cuentas con el valor `i`, el cual comienza desde 0.
Entonces estás contando: *(ejemplo: 10 + 10 + 10 - 10)*

`10, 10, 10` <- 1, 2, 3 (result.lenght = 3)

Recorrido del for: 
`0, 1, 2, 3` = Como ves, 4 posiciones.

Al momento de llegar a la 4 posición, ocurre el `NaN` (not a number), no tiene de donde coger un valor en esa posición, y arroja dicho error.

La corrección es simple: `i < result.length;`
Es decir, `Con i siendo menor a result.lenght`, esto reduce el recorrido del for a:
`0, 1, 2` = 3 posiciones = result.length

```js
let result = [];
    
const pushNum = ()=>{
    let num = 0;
    while (num>=0){
        num = parseInt(prompt('ingrese un número: ', '0'));
        if (num>=0){
           result.push(num);
           num=0;
        }  
    }
    console.log(result);
    let sume = 0;
    console.log(sume);
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sume = sume + result[i];
    }
    console.log(`La suma es: ${sume}`);
}

pushNum();
```

Comment: En función del ejemplo, la cuenta que da `NaN` es `6 + undefined` , por ello `sume + (result[i] || 0)` aunque confuso funcionaría con indices que no existen.

Comment: Estas confundiendo la cuenta, con la suma, el ejemplo suma 10+10+10-10. Sus posiciones, 0, 1, 2 ... por eso choque en el indice 3, dado que esa posicion no existe.

Comment: Ah si, y en el ejemplo ingresa un negativo, entonces sería `20 + undefined`

Comment: Segun entiendo, el proceso es, 10+10+10 = 30 ... el -10 lo usa como freno, porque, ni idea.

Comment: Buena respuesta, porque explicas el origen del error. Otra opción para simplificar sería el uso de `.reduce()`. Por cierto, el -10 es _"un freno"_ porque el ciclo tiene como condición `num >= 0` y no se agrega al arreglo.

Comment: A mi igual me perdió un momento lo del negativo al leer el problema, pero me di cuenta de lo mismo que dice triby. Quizás debería haber otro freno, como solo ingresar X cantidad de numeros, o pedir la cantidad antes, pero eso es cosa del OP.